# GeoLocation to find a coordinate getting kCLErrorDomain error 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, core-location

I am implementing a Geolocation code, which means the I want to take an address as a string and then return a location in the form of a CLCoordinate.  I get this strange error code that no one else is seeming to have seen.

**kCLErrorDomain error 8**

I don't have a map in this because I just want to be able to get a coordinate from an address string.  Then use this coordinate later for another part of the program.  I feel like I am missing something.  Thanks for all your help!

```
  @interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *BarSearch;

 @property (strong,nonatomic) CLGeocoder *Geocoder;
 @property (strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

//Check to see if they have Authorization to use to use location servieces
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

//Setup UISearch Bar
self.BarSearch.delegate=self;
```

}

The program does enter this method, but only to return this error:
**kCLErrorDomain error 8**

```
  -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{


self.Geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

[self.Geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Springfield, MA" completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
    if (!error) {

        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
        {
            NSLog(@"place--%@", [aPlacemark locality]);
            NSLog(@"lat--%f\nlong--   %f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude,aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude);
        }
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"error--%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake, but just by restarting the iOS Simulator the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added to your info plist this key : NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription